# Memory Allocation in Java Is Doubled

Tags: java, memory-management

I am wondering how can I be sure of the memory allocated by java. I have a program with limited memory requirements. When I allocate an array with a certain size, I notice that JVM allocate memory as much as double this size:

for example: before I allocate an array:

```
runtime.totalMemory() 15 MB
runtime.freeMemory(): 14 MB
```

After this line: char [] xxx = new char[4 * 1024 * 1024];

```
runtime.totalMemory() 15 MB
runtime.freeMemory(): 6 MB
```

So, amount of free memory dropped from 14 to 6 MB. Even though my array is only 4 MB. I have tried with different things arrays, it is always the same. Why does java allocates double the array size?

Thanks

Comment: Remember that a `char` is 16 bits, so 4 million `char`s is 8 MB, not 4 MB.

Answer (score 8):

A char is 16-bits, *not* 8. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for more details.

> char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has
>   a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or
>   65,535 inclusive).

So you're allocating `1024 * 1024 * 4 * 2` (2 bytes = 16 bits). Looks ok to me.

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback. But if I read byte by byte from the file and convert each byte to char, I can get back the character using a single byte not two bytes..?

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof(char)` for Java is 2 bytes, so a char array of 4 million elements displaces 8 mibibytes, which seems to be the exact amount you are missing from `freeMemory`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, a character is represented as unicode which is 2 bytes.

Comment: You mean "represented as UTF-16". Unicode is a character set, not a character encoding. And technically, some Unicode characters are represented as 4 bytes in UTF-16.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Although this statement **was** true back in 1995.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: No, back then Unicode was also a character set, not a character encoding, and then the correct statement would have been "represented as UCS-2".

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström It was completely common in colloquial usage to call Unicode 1.0 a 2-byte **text encoding**. Nobody even knew the term UCS-2. But nevermind, it's history, anyway.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: From http://www.unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html#14 : "UCS-2 is obsolete terminology which refers to a Unicode implementation up to Unicode 1.1" - But i agree that it was common to see Unicode as a 2-byte text encoding.